# How can I search for text in all tabs in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, search, browser-tabs

I have a number of opened tabs and I want to search for a word in all of them (just as you would do in any decent editor on you desktop).

I found an extension [Find In Tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8078/), but its outdated and doesn't work for recent versions..

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you don't find an alternative to this extension, you may still be able to use it in your version of firefox by bumping the max version. it's something I do quite a lot as I use the latest nightly builds from the trunk (3.7*) and branch (3.6.6) If an extension is relatively recent it should work in the 3.6* builds. Here's how:

1. Open the 'find in tabs.xpi' file with a zip like utility, I use 7zip but winzip/peazip/winrar etc will work.
2. Open the 'install.rdf' file in the archive with a text editor and find the line

3.5.*

3. Replace the value of 3.5.* with the version of firefox you are using; This can be found if you open the help menu and click the about link.
4. Save the file back into the xpi archive and close the archive.

This should now allow the extension to work in firefox.

There are other ways of doing this, for example the extension [MR Tech Toolkit](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/421) has an option for overriding compatibility checking. it can also be disabled in about:config [Extensions . checkCompatibility - MozillaZine Knowledge Base](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Extensions.checkCompatibility)

Comment: Unfortunately, not all extensions can have their max version changed without breaking or loosing some functionality. To some extent it depends how the extension has been coded. Usually, if an extension works with, say 3.6.3, and you have updated to 3.6.4, there's a pretty good chance everything will work as expected.

Answer (score 14):

Just put a % yoursearchtext in the adress bar of firefox.
For example: **% firefox**
You will get a dropdown box with all results.

Comment: Thanks, I also was not aware of this! However, it is slightly limited in that it only looks in titles...

Comment: Agreed, this does not do what the OP requested, although it is a handy feature if you have so many tabs open that you can't read the titles anymore.

Answer (score 4):

The [Fastest Search addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fastest-search/) allows you to do simple text (whole-word supported) or regular expression search in all tabs or only the selected/filtered tabs. It has many other useful features as well that'll save a lot of time for everyday browsing/searching.

Comment: Link is dead now

Answer (score 2):

There is new addons for that:

- [Hugo](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hugo/?src=cb-dl-updated)

  > Search all loaded tabs- similar to Find in Tabs, etc. except has much
  >   more functionality. This is a comprehensive tool designed for doing
  >   research. Please see screen shots and description.
- [FindBar Tweak](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/findbar-tweak/)

  > Anything between simple tweaks such as placing the findbar in the top
  >   corner, to the powerful "Find in All Tabs" tool, FindBar Tweak will
  >   make your find toolbar "just right"!

Comment: links to both extensions are dead

Answer (score 2):

The [Search all Tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/search-all-tabs/) works amazingly well and can search the content in all of all your tabs.

Extension [Homepage](https://webextension.org/listing/search-all-tabs.html)

```
Version         0.5.0  
Size            978.02 KB  
Last updated    Mar 1, 2023
```

Features:

1. Copy all URLs to the user's clipboard
2. Group all matched tab as a new window
3. Keyboard-only controls
4. Supports dark theme
5. Supports sidebar view
6. Supports deep search: display more matching snippets for a single tab

Answer (score 0):

FindBar Tweak [addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/findbar-tweak/) with last update ([1.1b2](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/findbar-tweak/#beta-channel) - beta now) included Find In Tabs code. 
(Apart this feature this can also show markers in scrollbar like Chrome and move findbar)

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021, Firefox now has built-in "Search Tabs" functionality.

1. Click "List all tabs" button (down carrot icon, in the upper-right corner)
2. Click "Search tabs"
3. Enter search term(s)
4. click  or

source: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/search-open-tabs-firefox

Comment: As mentioned above, this method only searches within a tab's title.

Answer (score 0):

For Quantum there is Search all Tabs https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/search-all-tabs/ and Search Multi Tabs https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/search-multi-tabs/