# Fix or replacement for thunderbird Buttons! plugin

Tags: plugins, thunderbird

I have been using Thunderbird [Buttons!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/106/) plug-in for years with Thunderbird 2.0, especially it's nifty Archive feature that lets you archive the message to one of the pre-set folder with a single mouse click.  Unfortunately this plug-in doesn't work with Thunderbird version 3.0.4 and later.  The plugin has not been updated since 2007.

So could anybody recommend any fix or replacement for this?

Answer (score 0):

I posted a solution to a similar problem here:

[How can I search for text in all tabs in Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/151927/how-can-i-search-for-text-in-all-tabs-in-firefox/151944#151944)

Although this is related to firefox the same principle works with thunderbird. To illustrate, I just downloaded the Buttons extension, changed the 'maxVersion to be compatible with the version of thunderbird I use (Lanikai v3.1.1pre) and the extension works:

```
<em:id>{3550f703-e582-4d05-9a08-453d09bdfdc6}</em:id>
    <em:minVersion>2.0b1</em:minVersion>
    **<em:maxVersion>3.1.1pre</em:maxVersion>**
```

[image]